# Graph encoding to use Graph Kernels for similarity measure between computer programs

Tags: graph, compiler-construction, machine-learning, svm

I am intending to use Graph Kernel to perform similarity measure between different computer programs. During compilation of computer program, they are represented as some form of graphs as depicted in the figure with control flow.

[image: Control Flow Graph]

The figure is extracted from the paper "Using Graph based program characterization for predictive modeling"

I am intending to use Graph kernels and for this purpose I am seeking help in how these graphs  could be encoded (format) with each node (basic block) containing feature vector (characteristics of that particular basic block) so that they can be fed to the kernel to calculate pre-computed matrices.

Comment: are these nodes unifable?  Does node "1" in one graph and node "1" in the second one encode the same type of entity? Or these are completely different graphs, and you only have "similarity" of nodes which can be expressed as similarity of features?

Comment: @lejlot Yes. Node "1" in graph one and Node "1" in graph two are similar only in terms of features. These features could be the number of instruction in the basic block or number of variables in the block and so on. But each node is attributed with a fixed length feature vector.

Answer (score 2):

Kernel functions defined for non-numerical objects like strings or graphs were introduced mostly to **avoid encoding** of this structures. The core idea is to compute the kernel value directly on objects from the non-numerical space, like in this example - graphs. Your particular example is an instance of labeled verticle graph (no labels on edges), so you can simply use the graph kernel for such structures. In the [Graph Kernels paper](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume11/vishwanathan10a/vishwanathan10a.pdf) it is introduced as a edge labeled structure, but change from edge labeling to vertice labeling is quite natural (and [already done in other papers](http://www.is.tuebingen.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/pdf2266.pdf)). So what remains is computation of similarity between particular vertice `v_i` and `v_j`. In oridignal paper we simply have a matrix `W` (responsible for expressing "similarity" of particular edge labelings) so analogusly you can compute some kind of similarity between vertices feature vectors (there are dozens possibilities, and choice of particular one is heavily data dependent, you can experiment with cosine similarity, hamming distance, MSE etc.), but the core idea remains the same. You first compute the vertice-vertice similarity matrix to use in the product graph and then simply apply corresponding graph kernel on your data. It is not simple solution, but I don't think that there exists the simple (good) one. Graph kernels are quite young objects (introduced 11 years ago) to work with really complex objects (and your particular problem is a great example of very complex object for classification). You should have in mind, that it can be **very** computationally expensive to use kernel methods on your graphs, and so it may be better idea to work with some simplier models (working on some simple features of your graphs instead of whole "raw" data).